# Convert event listener from jQuery to native Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the requeriment of jQuery in my app and I have this piece of code that handles an event related to a element.

So the original code is:

```
$(window.document).on('contextmenu', '.main td.active', function(e) {
    $("#context-menu").hide().css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    }).show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The migration is the following:

```
window.document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById("context-menu").style;
    el.left = e.pageX,
    el.top = e.pageY,
    el.display = 'block';
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is that the event (onContextmenu) is associated just only to the document.body ... then, when is fired, the event.target (mouse right-click) is checked to verify if matches with a .main td.active, instead of associate an event to each element.

(do not confuse with querySelector('.main td.active').addEventListener )

Any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Test the event target to see if it has the .main class. if it doesn't then you should return undefined to let the default action happen.

Comment: What about document.getElementsByClassName("main")

Answer (score 1):

You can define a fn `checkTarget()` something like the jQuery sizzle one would do in case if you have a CSS selector to find and use `querySelectorAll` and call that if returns true then the target is your specified selector so execute your fn else do nothing

```
window.document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    if(checkTarget(this, e.target, '.main td.active')){
        el = document.getElementById("context-menu").style;
        el.left = e.pageX,
        el.top = e.pageY,
        el.display = 'block';
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

function checkTarget(element, current, search){
   var matches = element.querySelectorAll(search);
   for(var i in matches){
      if(matches[i] === current){
          return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the event.target could be a child element of element.main  class

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign the event **directly** to the target elements using loops. Something like:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgcrteq4/1/)**

```
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
for( var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++ ){
     var target = parents[i].querySelectorAll('td.active');
     for( var j = 0; j < target.length; j++ ){
         target[j].oncontextmenu = function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             // do stuff
        };
     }
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that the event (onContextmenu) is associated just only to the document.body ... then, when is fired, the event.target (mouse right-click) is checked to verify if matches with a .main td.active, instead of associate an event to each element